# My laptop shuts down every time I unplug it

Tags: hardware, shutdown, laptop, battery

I am using a Lenovo G580 with Linux Mint 14 updated. My laptop shuts off every time I unplug it as if there is no battery even when I am using the BIOS. But, It detects the battery as "84% charging" and stuck in that way.

Should I replace the battery? If so, why does it detect it?

Comment: Might be the battery holds very little charge (not enough to keep the system powered on), yet it's seen as charged (because it is).

Comment: Check `dmesg`'s output. Is there anything possibly-related?

Comment: Thank you Renan. 
Nothing really helpful in dmesg. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check when my laptop shuts itself down after being disconnected from the power:

1. Try re-seating the battery for starters. Physically remove it and plug it back in.
2. Can the battery hold a charge? More difficult to diagnose but look under the a desktop applet to see if the battery is fully charged.
3. Is the laptop configured to shutdown when it gets to a certain threshold of battery charge left? Try changing this value to see if the laptop can get past being unplugged for any length of time. This will tell you that the issue is the battery.

For #3 take a look at `dconf-editor` to see if the laptop is setup to shutdown when the battery is critical.

[image: ss of dconf-editor]

You can also query these options from the command line using the `gsettings` command. Not sure if this command is available on all distros. I'm testing it on Ubuntu at the moment:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-ac false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 30
....
```

Comment: if you mean taking it out and putting it again, I already tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: @user98456 - yeah. I wasn't trying to be wise about it, just things to try.

Comment: The problem seems to be not with the OS because the problem also happens in BIOS. Anyway, Thank you for trying to help.